# Building react library using Rollup, How to avoid webpack alias in next.config.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, rollup

I've setup Rollup to build a React library, when importing the library into a SPA targeting client-side rendering apps(like an app made with create-react-app) everything is okay, but when using it in a next.js app, it complains with `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'` because it can't import `react` or `react-dom` and the only way to fix it now is to alias them in webpack config inside the `next.js` app(despite already being aliased in `rollup.config.js`)

I'm looking for a way to avoid this `alias` config in `next.config.js` file.

Here's my Rollup config

```js
const config = {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: {
        file: path.join(__dirname, "./dist/index.js"),
        format: "es",
    },
    external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    plugins: [

        alias({
            entries: [{
                    find: 'react',
                    replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react'),
                },
                {
                    find: 'react-dom',
                    replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-dom'),
                }]
        }),

        resolve({
            browser: true,
            // pass custom options to the resolve plugin
            moduleDirectories: ["node_modules"],
            dedupe: ["react", "react-dom"],
        }),
        replace({
            "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production"),
            preventAssignment: true,
        }),

        commonJS(),
    ],
};

export default config;
```

and here's how to solve the issue when importing the library in a `next.js` app

```js
// next.config.js
const path = require('path');


/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack(config) {

        config.resolve.alias = {
            ...config.resolve.alias,
            'react': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react'),
            'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react-dom')
        }

        return config;
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

The full code that's needed to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/lalosh/rollup-webpack-alias-issue

Answer (score -1):

I was able to successfully run the `react-library-test-app` from your example repository. Assuming you already have the `react-library` built with Rollup, go through the following steps.

###### #1 - Add `@lalosh/rollup-webpack-alias-issue` to the dependencies of `react-library-test-app`.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@lalosh/rollup-webpack-alias-issue": "1.0.0",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
}
```

###### #2 - npm link `@lalosh/rollup-webpack-alias-issue`

From the `react-library` folder run the following command:

```
npm link
```

Then from the `react-library-test-app` folder run:

```
npm link @lalosh/rollup-webpack-alias-issue
```

###### #3 - Remove webpack configuration

Finally, remove the extra webpack configuration in `next.config.js`.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Then run the app in development mode with `npm run dev`. The app should be able to run without any errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, but unfortunately it didn't work, it still shows the same error: 
```Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'
> 1 | import e from"react";function t(){return e.createElement("p",null,"Test me")}export{t as TestComponent};```

Comment: It might be worth cleaning all `node_modules` folders and/or `.next` folder and try again with a clean slate.

Comment: I've just tried that, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Do you think we can try something else to solve this?